# Does WebCodecs support transparency of an HEVC stream?

Tags: google-chrome, hevc, webcodecs

I checked out this demo [from the webcodecs repo](https://github.com/w3c/webcodecs/tree/main/samples/video-decode-display) and I was playing around with the HEVC decoding, which works from Chrome 107 I believe.

However, when I tried with an HEVC that utilizes transparency, the transparent part is drawn with black. I played the same video using the video element and it was transparent. I'm wondering, is it possible to preserve the transparent using the VideoDecoder?

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/webcodecs/issues/377

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad to see you are testing this feature, HEVC with Alpha for macOS has been initially supported since Chrome 107, and has been fully supported since Chrome 108, so you can try Chrome Canary 108 and its should already working well with WebCodec + VideoDecoder API now.

The implement for HEVC with alpha on Windows will be much more complex and hasn't been implemented yet, but I may take some time to implement it as well.

Comment: Thank you it indeed works like a charm on the 108! Having this on Windows too would be amazing!

Comment: Is there a schedule for having the HEVC with alpha support on Windows too? I'm working on a fallback in the meantime for Windows but it would make my life easier by a mile! Thanks for your amazing work so far!

Comment: I was working on HEVC encoding recently. Since it has been finished last week i will start developing this feature since this weekends. I couldn’t give you a estimate time since as i mentioned this is much more complicated then HEVC with Alpha on macOS

Comment: You can watch this repo https://github.com/StaZhu/enable-chromium-hevc-hardware-decoding  to follow the news of new HEVC features, i will update the repo once the implement is done.